# Changing the bibliography style

Tags: biblatex

I want the title of the article be like the title of the book, i.e. in `textit` and without the quotation marks. Is that somehow possible?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=alphabetic,maxnames=10]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{references.bib}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{references.bib}
@book{key,
  author = {Baur, S and Schmid, A},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Title},
  publisher = {Publisher},
}
@Article{key2,
  Title                    = {Extensions},
  Author                   = {Author},
  Journal                  = {Adv. Math.},
  Year                     = {2000},
  Pages                    = {100},
  Volume                   = {1},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

Comment: `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}` will make *all* titles italic. If you only want `@article`s, go with `\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```

to change *all* titles to italic/emphasis.

To only change `@article`s use

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
```